# 1.12: Recipe book disappeared

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started to play with Minecraft v1.12 and already used the recipe book but since yesterday it disappeared from the inventory.

Is there a short cut to re-enable it or does anyone know what happened?

Comment: There's a green book icon in your inventory. Try clicking that. If it doesn't help, try giving more details: Are you still playing in 1.12? Is it singleplayer or multiplayer? Did you change anything before it happened?

Comment: I used the green book; now the inventory looks like the <1.12 inventory. I did not do anything, maybe I hit some button ...

Comment: Click the green book again, it should come back.

Comment: There is no green bock anymore ... as I told you: Looks like the <1.12 inventory.

Comment: Do you have any resource packs active?

Comment: Yes, I do - but it used to work with the packs as well - it stopped while being IN the world, no logout between working and not working.

Comment: The recipe menu is a new texture, so a resource pack would not overwrite it. But the icon in the inventory is very likely part of either the inventory texture or the GUI items texture, so it would be overwritten by a 1.11- resource pack. Try disabling the pack, it won't hurt. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63992/discussion-between-hannes-and-fabian).

Comment: If you want to do that, I can only continue in some hours, because my work PC blocks chats.

Comment: It seems like you have solved your problem based on recommendations in chat. You should consider self answering this question so that others can see how you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem at one point.  I was very confused for a while.  Verify your resource pack is for 1.12 or 1.12.1, otherwise the book is not visible.  One way to test this is to click where the recipe book is supposed to be(which is under the inventory craft grid).

[image: Click Here]

If this works, you will see this:
[image: Book]

Even when the book is open, you will not see it's button.

Turn off your current resource pack to see the button.

---

Edit:  I was playing with resource packs because of your question.  I created a resource pack that only contains vanilla inventory screen and craft table of 1.12.1. If you like your current resource pack but want the recipe book button, load [this resource pack](https://www.mediafire.com/file/z205z1jnyekvhpc/Add%20Recipe%20Book.zip) over the top of the old one.

Make sure my resource pack is at top of list:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my Resource pack, though it claims to be compatible with 1.12 appears not to have the book thingy. If I open the book without Resource packs and than add the pack it is still opened.